Storybook for react cant see my components
When I run my storybook sometimes my components are missing.

So I have
"... New folder\workingtestwithpawel\src\components\Ai4Process_mylib_test2\demo.stories.tsx"

But storybook won't see the file
Here is my .storybook/main.js which defines where to look for stories.
/** @type { import('@storybook/react-webpack5').StorybookConfig } */
const config = {
  stories: ['../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)'],
  addons: ['@storybook/addon-links', '@storybook/addon-essentials'],
  framework: {
    name: '@storybook/react-webpack5'
  },
  docs: {
    autodocs: 'tag'
  }
};
export default config;

What do I need to do to fix it so storybook sees my components?
I'm still unable to get storybook to see my component but could the error be due to this seeming to hang?


To get answer quickly, It would be helpful if you could share a simplified version of your project that includes your configuration (Webpack, Babel, etc.), along with a basic HelloWorld component and a corresponding story. Hosting this example on GitHub or CodeSandbox would make it easier for others to understand your setup and provide more accurate assistance. Additionally, having a reproducible example can help identify the issue more quickly and may also benefit others facing similar problems.

It looks like you have accidentally shared your private keys on a public GitHub repo. Please discard the keys and create new ones as soon as possible. Additionally, please be advised that a link to GitHub is not [mcve] and should not be included in the question. Please make sure that the text of the question has all the necessary information, and only that, to reproduce the problem.

@Dharman  this is a blank project i'm only using as an example. I never intend to use this outside of this example. The keys were just automatically created when i made the project folder with npm.
with all that considered, is there any danger?

I was able to pull the repository on my computer (a Mac) and see the story without changing anything, which means the configuration is correct. Here are a few hypotheses on why it might not be working in your case:

Corrupted Node modules:

Try deleting the node_modules directory in your project.
Remove package-lock.json.
Run npm install again.


Legacy Node runtime:

Current supported NodeJS versions are v18 and above. I tested both Node 18 and Node 20 with your example, and both worked correctly.
You can download and install Node 20 from NodeJS, then:

Remove node_modules and package-lock.json.
Run npm install again to see if the updated Node version resolves the issue.




Windows file system:

This might be harder to troubleshoot if your configuration works on Mac/Linux but not on Windows.
The longest path name allowed in Windows is around 256 characters in some Windows settings. This length includes both the folder and file names, so if the file is deep in the folder structure, it might exceed this limit.
Start by renaming the component and story with shorter names.
Move your project folder up in the file system so the total path length is shorter.



